# How to disable drop down list

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

I have this drop down list and my idea is when i click on videos that i disable other drop down list.This is not working.Do i need something else?

```
<select name="Type" id="type">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option name="image" value="I" >Images</option>
  <option name="video "value="V">Videos</option>
  <?php 
$value=$_POST['image'];
?>
</select>

<select id="text-one" <?php if($value=="V"){ ?> disabled="disabled"<?php }?> >
                <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
                <option value="Dig">Digital</option>
    </select
```

Comment: Yeah, you need JavaScript instead of PHP.

Comment: As The DOCTOR pointed this out - you want to have something happening in the web, on the client side, and not on the server that generates static page that is being then shown to the user. Check jquery site for javascript and nice support of things you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with PHP, but that's going to require submitting form the data so you can then access `$_POST`, and then loading a new page, that's basically the same as the original, just with text-one disabled.

Remember, PHP runs server side, and once it's rendered in the browser, nothing else can be done via PHP.   For example, you've got a line in your sample code that show's you tring to assign `$_POST['image']` to `$value` - until you submit a form, `$_POST` will be empty.

Most likely, you want to do this client side and without a reload, and this can be done using javascript.

As a basic overview:

1. monitor the `onChange` event handler for your `type` select element
2. check the value of the `type` select element, and set the `disabled` attribute on the `text-one` as needed

Another option (maybe simpler?):

attach an `onclick` attribute to the video input, that will run a javascript function that disables `text-one`

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) will make some of this easier, but you could write all of the above in plain javascript, without any libraries.

Answer (score 2):

try this code :

```
<script>
  function disable(val)
  {
      if(val=="V")
           document.getElementById("text-one").disabled=true;
      else
          document.getElementById("text-one").disabled=false;
  }
</script>

<select name="Type" id="type" onchange="disable(this.value)">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option name="image" value="I" >Images</option>
  <option name="video "value="V">Videos</option>
</select>

<select id="text-one" >
      <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
       <option value="Dig">Digital</option>
</select>
```